# Converting a nested index-match function to VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I'm using this formula to match two dates, between sheet3 and sheet2, then print the appropriate value in when the dates match. Millions of rows to run it over and this formula makes the files too large and calculation impossible.
`=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$G$60,MATCH(A2,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$60,0),6)),"",INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$G$60,MATCH(A2,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$60,0),6))`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what would this formula be in a vba code is my question

Comment: In VBA it is the same using the `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` property of the Range Object. If however you want to use VBA to speed up the process,  one way is to use Arrays. So the idea is to pass the data your working on to it and do the matching usibg the array then return the values to the ranges. There are many post here on that route. You can also use `Dictionary`object.

Answer (score 1):

You use the exact same index/match function two times in this formula, instead you can use the function IFERROR to return an empty string when no match is found. See the code example below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$G$60,MATCH(A2,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$60,0),6)),"")
```

To optimize further your formula you can specify the third argument of the match function (match_type) to make the formula do a binary tree search on the column Sheet3!A  , it will calculate much faster this way even for a very big range. But to make this work, first you need to sort the column Sheet3!A in ascending order. See the code example below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$G$60,MATCH(A2,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$60,1),6)),"")
```